# Salvaging a Damaged Miniature Rose

Tags: roses

My fiancee has a miniature rose she was given as a gift, which we keep indoors as we live in an apartment. After recovering from being left in an abandoned office for a week or so, it's been thriving - survived a summer, this last winter, and into this summer.

This summer however, it got hit with a very bad case of powdery mildew, and by the time we managed to get something to treat it, it's sustained some pretty bad damage. Essentially all its leaves are curled and brittle, and it looks "dead" - or close to it.

Is there something that can be done to salvage it? Is there a place to cut to essentially encourage new growth and starting over? Or is it on its way out?

Answer (score 1):

It might be on its way out, unfortunately. I don't know what you sprayed with, but in future, if you have no suitable fungicide and it happens again, mix 1 part cow's milk to 9 parts water in a spray bottle and spray with that, till run off, under the leaves as well as on top.
In the meantime, some emergency treatment might be worth carrying out - cut the stems down to about 2 inches and check whether it needs a bigger pot by turning it out of the pot it's in and seeing if its rootbound. If it does need potting on, then do that, using fresh potting compost. If it doesn't, then feed it, ordinary houseplant food will do at this stage for its nitrogen content. Don't overwater at this stage - it may not be using too much with no topgrowth, but water when the surface of the compost feels dry to the touch, but not shrunken from the sides of the pot. And keep your fingers crossed...